# where is ipc_namespace.h in linux

Tags: linux, ipc

I need to study something and change in the ipc_namespace.h but I cannot find it. Can someone please specify the correct path to it and also let me know if I can some thing in that file and restart my OS will the changes take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me: `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-27-generic/include/linux/ipc_namespace.h` and for you possibly depends on you kernel version.

Use: `apt-file search ipc_namespace.h` to locate it.

About changing it, no a simple restart will not do the trick, you will need to recompile highly possibly your kernel for the changes to happen. (And I'm not an expert in this area :( )

Comment: yes i figured it out that it will vary from kernel version. Anyway Thanks :)

Comment: what if i changed something in this file and i have to recompile it?